# Invoke two subscribe methods onInit

Tags: angular

I've written the code below and categories are not displayed in html template. However when I remove getSubject() and place its code inside getSubjects() method everything works fine. Why I can't have these two methods separated?

```
export class SubjectComponent implements OnInit {

  subject: Subject;
  subjects = [];
  constructor(private subjectService: SubjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSubjects();
    this.getSubject();
  }
  getSubjects(){
    this.subjectService.getSubjects().subscribe(result => {
      this.subjects = result;
    });
  }
  getSubject(){
    this.subjects.forEach((s: Subject) => {
      if (s.name.toLowerCase() === 'math'){
        this.subject = s;
      }
    });
  }
```

Html template:

```
{{subject?.name}}
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let category of subject?.categories">
    <p>{{category?.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What happens in your code: `getSubjects()` triggers some async request. Then `getSubject()` fills `this.subject` then the callback in your getSubjects() method is called and fills `this.subjects` - that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to call them separately?
Basically, when you call your service it goes and gets the data. When the data is returned (at some point in time) the `subscribe` code is executed. When that data comes back would be when you want to iterate through it and set the subject. Calling `getSubject()` as you had it would have a high chance of trying to iterate through an empty array because the data has not yet been returned.

Here is how I would structure my onInit:

```
export class SubjectComponent implements OnInit {

    subject: Subject;
    subjects: Subject[] = [];

    constructor(private subjectService: SubjectService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subjectService.getSubjects().subscribe(result => {
            this.subjects = result;
      
            this.subjects.forEach((s: Subject) => {
                if (s.name.toLowerCase() === 'math'){
                    this.subject = s;
                }
            });

      });
  }
```